# GAE Python app won't start "No URLMap entries found in application configuration"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am following the first exercise in a book called "Google App Engine With Python" and have created a directory called `clock` with two files in it named `app.yaml` and `main.py` and I have copied the code exactly from the book but I can't get it started with `dev_appserver.py`. I think it may be something to do with the URL handlers in `app.yaml` but as I said I have copied it exactly so not sure what the problem is. When I run `dev_appserver.py clock` in terminal this happens:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 346, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 334, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 94, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 929, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 132, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 499, in _parse_configuration
    config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/Users/James/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 93, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    'No URLMap entries found in application configuration')
google.appengine.api.appinfo_errors.MissingURLMapping: No URLMap entries found in application configuration
```

Here is my code for app.yaml:

```
application: clock
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*

script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Here is my code for main.py

```
import datetime
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    message = '<p>The time is: %s</p>' % datetime.datetime.now()
    self.response.out.write(message)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handlers` section in app.yaml is not formatted correctly.  The `script:` part needs to be indented under the url pattern, like this:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.application
```